# What breaks Wudu exactly? (Quran references only)

Tags: wudu, quran-only

I've been doing some research on what would break or nullify Wudu, but the answers never have references to the Quran.

In what ayah(s) does it state what breaks Wudu? The reply I am looking for would only consist of Quran references; please refrain from answers that rely on hadiths or third-party explanations of God's verses.

Answer (score 1):

According to quran you need to do wudu' for every prayer. Based on (5:6)

> O you who have believed, when you rise to [perform] prayer, wash your faces and your forearms to the elbows and wipe over your heads and wash your feet to the ankles.

What breaks wudu' isn't mentioned there as quran doesn't mention details but overall rules.